# What's the most efficient way to setup a foreign key with a char value on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database

So I'm working on this project that is going to use a SQL Server database.

The "main" table has a column called `Hazard`, which has standardized values saved on a Hazard dictionary. For that reason, I created a table that will contain those hazard values and the main table will reference it.

This is how the structure is done:

```
CREATE TABLE main 
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    hazard char(14) NOT NULL,
    // other columns
    FOREIGN KEY(hazard) REFERENCES hazards(id)
);

CREATE TABLE hazards
(
    id CHAR(14) PRIMARY KEY,
    // Hazard specification columns here
);
```

The part I'm not sure about is "repeating" the hazard id. It is standardized as a 14 characters string, so I used a CHAR type for this.

Should I make a `id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY` on hazard so the foreign key on the main is an int type? Does it actually improve the database size?

Comment: How many different hazards are you likely to have? I *doubt* you are going to have ~4 billion, so in fact a `smallint` or `tinyint` might be even better choices. A `char(14)` is 14 bytes in size, where as `smallint` and `tinyint` are 2 and 1 bytes in size respectively.

Comment: There are currently 32 Hazards, but there's a process to eventually add more.

Comment: Would you therefore say there is a very good chance there will be more than 256 in the future? If not, then a `tinyint` with an `IDENTITY(0,1)` might be a potential choice.

Comment: I don't think there will be that many. So I can probably do it as you suggested.

Comment: I don't think there is one right answer here, and if you search for "natural vs surrogate keys" you'll probably find hundreds of articles each offering a slightly different take on the debate. Storing an int will definitely take less space, but this may not be consequential in the grand scheme of things. I typically use surrogate keys, and have the natural key as an alternate key in the reference table, but that is just my preference - there are equally good cases for the use of natural keys and the debate will no doubt continue for years to come.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between char(14) (14 bytes) and int (4 bytes) is quite significant. Using an identity column also has performance advantages in terms of sorting since the sort order will be based on record age and in terms of write performance because if you let SQL determine the key it doesn't have to check the unique constraint for every insert into hazard.

For your use case I don't think it will matter, but in general it's wise to follow best practices and using identity columns as keys is a good habbit.

Comment: I agree in principle - I typically also prefer to use `INT IDENTITY` columns. But with *only* 32 values in the lookup table - I doubt 14 bytes vs. 4 bytes will make a measurable difference..... if we'd be talking about 32 *billion* rows - yes, then definitely!

Comment: I'm happy to see people questioning decisions like this. It could very well prove to be a completely irrelevant decision, but his next fk relationship might as well end up being referenced billions of times over its lifetime.